# Calcite ArrayIteratorCursor support for Blobs, Clobs, Array

Tags: apache-calcite

We are using Calcite version 1.35.0 (Avatica version 1.23.0).  We create a connection and add a Schema to it via:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:");
final CalciteConnection calciteConnection;
calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
final SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();
rootSchema.add(DB_SCHEMA, JdbcSchema.create(rootSchema, DB_SCHEMA, dataSource, null, DB_SCHEMA));
return connection;
```

When querying via JPA against an H2 db that has a table containing a "Binary Large Object" column (a Blob) the following code gets invoked:
`CalciteJdbc41Connection` creates a `CalciteJdbc41PreparedStatement` which creates a `CalciteResultSet` (a subclass of `AvaticaResultSet`) which then creates an `ArrayIteratorCursor` (a subclass of AbstractCursor) which has this implementation:

```
public Blob getBlob() throws SQLException {
  throw cannotConvert("Blob");
}
```

Is there anything I can do to support Blobs/Clobs/Arrays/Refs/etc (they all throw cannotConvert exceptions)?  Maybe I'm doing something incorrectly in my Connection initialization.  I am NOT initializing anything with the `RelOptPlanner` like Rules as it didn't appear that I needed to.  Is this a limitation of the `org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver` class only supporting `org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteJdbc41Factory` thus far?

In case it's helpful this is the stackTrace:
[image]